# Django search with greek characters

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have tried a lot of backends in my django application, always using unaccent extension.

The django documentation mentions that if you search this:

```
Author.objects.filter(name__unaccent__icontains='Helen')
You get this:
[<Author: Helen Mirren>, <Author: Helena Bonham Carter>, <Author: Hélène Joy>]
```

But how can this work for greek characters also?
I have a product with **title='σουπερ'**
and when i search like this

```
Product.objects.filter(title_el__unaccent__icontains='σουπερ')
```

I get this:

```
<ProductQuerySet [<Product: σουπερ>]>
```

But if i search like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(title_el__unaccent__icontains='σούπερ')
```

I get this:

```
<ProductQuerySet []>
```

So maybe unaccent works for english characters only (Spanish in the django documentation is english characters)? And if so how can I extend this functionality for greek characters?

Comment: which version of postgre do you use

Comment: 9.6.15 I see here https://gist.github.com/marinoszak/7d5d6a8670faae0f4589c2da988f2ba3
the rules for postgre 9.6 and they seem to be doing what i want

Comment: did you add rules to proper folder

Comment: ah sorry I just now learned that i have to add the rules by myself from the post below. I thought they were include in the postgre 9.6

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 12 unaccent supports Greek characters out of box, for lower version you should add rules yourself

From [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/unaccent.html) documentation

> RULES is the base name of the file containing the list of translation
> rules. This file must be stored in $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/ (where
> $SHAREDIR means the PostgreSQL installation's shared-data directory).
> Its name must end in .rules (which is not to be included in the RULES
> parameter).

You could use [gist](https://gist.github.com/marinoszak/7d5d6a8670faae0f4589c2da988f2ba3) file you already linked in comments